# How do I filter bad words when I'm adding Google Translate to my app

Tags: google-translate

I don't see the function of filtering bad words in cloud translation guides and references. Does cloud tranlsation have the funciton? I want to filter bad words when I'm using google translate in my app because I'm seeing that bad words are not censored. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.